# How to remove Infinite loop in ~/.bashrc?

Tags: ubuntu

I was trying to run a small shell script which creates infinite loop. It was working and it would stop if I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

But, I put that piece of code in `~/.bashrc`. Now if I open my terminal it runs an infinite loop and I'm not able to do anything. Prompt is not appearing. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either rename the `.bashrc` file to another name in the file manager
OR
You could edit the file with a GUI text editor to remove the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But, where to find .bashrc file? I searched in file manager ..I fot bash.bashrc but when o opened it in editor.. It was a different one.it didn't contain my code in it.

Comment: It should be in your home directory. "dot files" (those starting with .) are hidden by default, so you will need to enable this (sorry I don't have a Ubuntu GUI in front on me right now, so don't know which menu this is on).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I searched for hidden files in home! I got it! It worked!